# Converting PDF values to excel in specific format

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I have some plain data in a PDF as shown below. [image]

I need to get this data and convert it to put in an excel file like this [image]

I am confused if there is a direct method in Microsoft Excel 2007 and above to directly take values from PDF and paste it in this format.

So far what I've tried is itextSharp with C# coding. It doesnot seem to support convertion from PDF to excel and even though I've tried, I couldnot get in this format of excel. I shall put updates to my further findings in this question itself.

Comment: It would seem to me, that you would need to pull the information out of the PDF, perhaps using ITextSharp.  Then push the formatted information into Excel using [Excel Interop.](http://www.dotnetperls.com/excel)

Comment: Any code if you could kindly provide would be really helpful because my cursor is still blinking not knowing what to code.

Comment: lol... the link i gave you on interop will walk you through creating an excel file.  I've not worked w/ ITextSharp, I assumed because you mentioned it, you knew how to use it to read a PDF.